# Saving listview items to notepad

Tags: c#, winforms, save, notepad

I'm trying to save the items in my listview in a notepad, my code works however I'm getting the controls not the item itself

Here's my code:

```
File.AppendAllText(str_LogsDirectory + @"\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy") + ".txt" , list_log.Items.ToString());
```

Comment: You're calling `ToString` on the collection - not on each item in the collection.

Comment: You got to loop through items. Also it is recommended to use `Path.Combine` for combining path.

Comment: @HassanNisar Ow, right I forgot the index of the item

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `ToString()` on a `ListViewCollection`, which just returns the type of object. That's not what you want...

Assuming your `ListView` is just a list of strings (I don't know what the actual data type is that you're populating it with), try this:

```
var logDir = Path.Combine(str_LogsDirectory, DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy") + ".txt");

File.AppendAllText(logDir, String.Join(",", list_log.Items.Cast<string>()));
```

It will generate a comma-delimited string of all the items and append that to your file. If you're using a more complicated class to populate the ListView, then you'll have to do a little more work than this.

Comment: Quick question, how do I break line while appending it in notepad `\n` or `Environment.NewLine` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
string sPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(str_LogsDirectory, DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy") + ".txt");

using(System.IO.StreamWriter SaveFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(sPath))
{
   foreach(var item in list_log.Items)
   { 
       SaveFile.WriteLine(item.ToString());
   }
}
```

**UPDATE** (To include sub items of the ListView):

```
using(System.IO.StreamWriter SaveFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(sPath))
{
   foreach(ListViewItem item in list_log.Items)
   { 
       string sLine = item.ToString();

       for(int i=0; i<item.SubItems.Count;i++)
       {
            sLine += item.SubItems[i].Text;                
       } 

       SaveFile.WriteLine(sLine);           
   }
}
```

Note: Include space between items according to your requirement.

Comment: It only gets 1 column in my listview.